# Genshi template serialization memory usage

Tags: python, xml, templates, memory, genshi

I'm trying to generate XML files with Genshi templates. Since the files are around 100MB and my available memory small, I have tried to memory optimize my code by not loading my data but instead using python generators.

However, using

```
tpl = MarkupTemplate("<template_xml/>")
stream = tpl.generate(data=lots_of_data_generator)
with open('file.xml', 'w') as fp:
    for chunk in stream.serialize():
        fp.write(chunk)
```

still hogs a lot of memory, which according to the profiler happens in the second line. 
The [Genshi doc](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/streams.html#serialization) states calling serialize() on a stream returns a generator instead of a loaded string, which I thought would return values on the fly on not load all in memory. Is this incorrect thinking? Is there a way to not use so much memory with templates?

Comment: The above code has an error in it. You use two quote marks instead of one.